# DexGuard with UiAutomator and Monkey(not monkey runner)

Tags: android-uiautomator, monkey, dexguard

has anyone used uiautomator or monkey to automate ui testing for an app that has been obfuscated by Dexguard?  could you share your experience? like could uiautomator identify the widget by resourceID/Text etc. or if monkey could still run its random events after the app's package's name been obfuscated?

Answer (score 0):

after try out the DexGuard. UiAutomator and Monkey works just fine.